# Xcode 8 Cordova.h file not found

Tags: ios, cordova, continuous-integration, xcode8

Using Xcode 8 and the beta for Server (5.4). Trying to get automated builds to work but keep getting Error 'Cordova/CDVPlugin.h' file not found. This only happens when archiving from a bot. If i archive from the build machine just through Xcode, it archives fine. There was a similar issue when Xcode 7 came out that required a change to the header search paths. Anyone have a solution to this yet?

[Xcode 7 Cordova Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546607/xcode-7-2-in-archive-getting-the-issue-cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-n)

Answer (score 0):

Try `cordova platform update ios` but be careful, for some reason it messes up cordova plugin accessibility somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Xcode 8.3.3:

1. go to Build Settings
2. find Search Paths > Framework Search Paths
3. add the path to where your exact Cordova library is stored on the current machine; make sure it's Cordova/Frameworks if your actual path (in Finder) has the Cordova.framework package nested in a /Frameworks sub folder
4. Clean
5. Build / Run again