# ionic app archive failing in xcode 7.2 due to ‘Cordova/CDVViewController.h’ file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, xcode-project

I am developing an ionic app for iOS and it is building fine, but when I archive it in xcode, it is throwing "‘Cordova/CDVViewController.h’ file not found" error in xcode 7.2.

I have tried usual suspects such as solution suggested in https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-in-xcode-7-1-beta/32232, but nothing worked. I have also tried archiving in xcode 7.1, 6.4 but the same error exists. I am using ionic 1.2.4.

Some of my project screenshots (if it helps)

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

let me know if you need more info.

Comment: You may be experiencing this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379291/cordova-app-failing-to-archive-with-xcode-7-1-cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file/33380045#33380045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @David I tried your answer. Didn't work. However, I tried ionic's weather app and it worked. So I thought the issue might be with my environment. I cut out js, css and views folder and put it in a fresh repo and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

2 things to try

1st)
you have screen shotted your header search paths i don't see a path to Cordova
try adding `$(SRCROOT)/WhereCordovaIS` to the header search paths

also do the same for Library Search Paths

2nd) 
In the Cordova Lib make sure the headerFiles that are missing 'CDVViewController.h' is included in the 'copy files build step' in BuildPhases
is in the copy