# Xcode 7.2 Cannot create an Archive - Error says “Cordova/CDVViewController.h’ file not found ”

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I have been over all the earlier posts, questions and answers - most of which advise to update the `Build Settings` and `Header Search Paths`. I have followed all this advice with no resolution. 
My header search path is set to the below folders:

```
$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include 
$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include 
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)
$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include
```

I have also now updated my Cordova version and am using 5.5 and a platform ios version of 3.9.2 - this update made no difference.

`My Preference -> Locations -> Advanced Build Location` is already Unique.

Please help. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For xcode7 add `"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"` to your Header Search Paths.

Comment: I have already added that path, as I said in the original question, but it has not worked. Do you have any other suggestions please?

Comment: After adding above line clean the project  and restart xcode. Also note: The build settings tab defaults to the 'Basic' filter. Make sure that 'All' is selected or you won't see the Header Search Paths field

Comment: also, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379291/cordova-app-failing-to-archive-with-xcode-7-1-cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file

Comment: Thank you for your attention on this. I have already followed all the advice I can find on StackOverflow, including the link you included above. I have change the path. Cleaned and restarted several times. There is something else that I am missing.

Comment: Should the path be applied in the Build Settings to the Project as well as the Targets?

Comment: OK. I finally took the time to build a brand new phonegap project after having upgraded to 5.5 yesterday and compared the default build settings to what I had updated into my old project.

Comment: I realised that I had put the changed Header Search Path from the other helpful answers into the actual line that says 'Header Search Paths' <Multiple Values> so that the new string applied to both the Debug and Release items. The new project showed me that the additional path should only be added to the release line. And the <Multiple Values> should therefore be left blank. The Debug line shouldn't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I had put the changed Header Search Path from the other helpful answers into the actual line that says 'Header Search Paths' <Multiple Values> so that the new string applied to both the Debug and Release items. The additional path should only be added to the Release line. And the <Multiple Values> should therefore be left blank. The Debug line shouldn't be changed.