# Cordova app failing to Archive with Xcode 7.3 (Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found)

Tags: xcode, cordova, ipa

I have a project with Cordova(6.1.1)/Phonegap(5.3.10). I am trying to build an ipa file with Xcode 7.3. When I click on Product > Archive the build fails, and the log says: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found. I can successfully build the project to a device, so i am kinda lost knowing what the problem might be.

I have tried to change the Header Search Path
from

"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include"

to

"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"

from reading this post
[Xcode 7.2: In “Archive”: Getting the issue: “Cordova/CDVViewController.h’ file not found ”. While there is no such issues in building the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546607/xcode-7-2-in-archive-getting-the-issue-cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-n)

I have tried to change chage to enable bitcode to "no", but still no luck at Archiving my app.

From many readings here on stackoverflow the issue seems to be with header search path, but this havent solved my issue. Dont know if there is something else on Xcode 7.3, because the other posts is with Xcode 7.2 and below. Dont know how to solve this issue, has anyone else experienced this problem?

**Update (Solution):**

Under Build Settings > Deployment > Install owner. I left that blank and then it finally worked.

Comment: did you tried doing it in both debug and release sections of Header Search Paths?

Comment: Try this out: 
    1) Run this in your terminal: cordova platform update ios
    2) Open your project in Xcode
    3) Go to Preference -> Locations -> Advanced
    4) Choose "Unique" as the option for Build Location
    5) Product -> Clean
    6) Product -> Build

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Tried it, but still no luck.

Comment: Just tested in Xcode7.3(7D175), cordova 6.1.1 Works fine for me

Comment: For the record, @Gandhi's method worked for me with Xcode 7.3.1 and Cordova 6.2.0.

Comment: @wumbo thanks for the update. Have posed the answer, please upvote if it helped so that others get benefited too.cheers

Answer (score 17):

Try this out, this should work.

- Run this in your terminal: cordova platform update ios
- Open your project in Xcode
- Go to Preference -> Locations -> Advanced
- Choose "Unique" as the option for Build Location
- Product -> Clean
- Product -> Build

Try out `cordova platform update ios`  as well as it fixed the problem for the questioner

Comment: `cordova platform update ios` was what I was missing to solve this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gandhi THANK YOU!!

Comment: to me, it was --> Choose "Unique" as the option for Build Location

Comment: Wow, I spent quite some time looking for the answer and this solved it. Thank you! The Ionic/Cordova project was building fine from the terminal. Building it in Xcode 9 failed. It was not project specific, because it was the same for every Ionic/Cordova project. For me the solution was also choosing 'Unique' as the option for Build Location. It was set to 'Legacy'.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tried all the suggestions above and still it does not work.  You can try these:
First check if you have this folder "CordovaLib", under: platforms->ios

Second, make sure you have the icons and splash images in your "resources" folder.
if not:
$ ionic resources

then run:
ionic platform remove ios
ionic platform add ios

These commands will install "CordovaLib" folder, then do the build again.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work with Xcode 8. You have to reinstall latest version of cordova, and remove platform and add it again

```
npm un cordova
sudo npm install -g cordova // yarn global add cordova
```